# Get the nth activity that the user sent to the bot

Tags: botframework

I want my bot to send the user a message after every 3 messages(activities) the user send. Is there a method in the bot framework to detect the number of the activity sent or the count of all past activities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bot is stateless by default, however you could save the 'activity counter' in the user / conversation data. Retrieve and increment this counter at every incoming message.

Microsoft Docs: [Save user and conversation data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)